# Image search in Django

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql, django-templates

I'm trying to query images stores in 'Static' and stored in Postgres. How do I format the HTML to call the image from the Static folder based on the name?

HTML file:

```
      {% for image in object_list %}


  {{ image.name }}, {{ image.photo }}
```

it only shows the name of the image, not the view.

models.py

```
class image(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="static")

class Meta:
  verbose_name_plural = "images"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
model = image
template_name = 'search.html'

def get_queryset(self): # new
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = image.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(photo__icontains=query)
    )
    return object_list
```

Comment: What's the issue? The images aren't being displayed?

Comment: Correct. It only show the name of the image file

Comment: change to ```{{ image.photo.url }}```

Comment: it would find the photo but only show the name of the photo's file "photo.jpg" not the actual photo. I was thinging maybe the problem is with HTML so I put ' <img src="{{ image.photo.url }}" width="100" height="150" />' but still wouldn't show the image